# I have a problem with repeatable -> select2_from_array field in BackPack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have this code:
**Controller**

```
        $this->crud->addField(
        [
            'name'   => 'schedule',
            'label'  => 'Schedule',
            'type'   => 'repeatable',
            'fields' => [
                [
                    'name'        => 'day',
                    'label'       => 'Day',
                    'type'        => 'select_from_array',
                    'options'     => Day::titles(),
                    'allows_null' => false,
                ],
                [
                    'name'            => 'range',
                    'label'           => 'Range',
                    'type'            => 'select2_from_array',
                    'options'         => $this->getScheduleRange(),
                    'default'         => $this->getDefaultScheduleRange(),
                    'allows_null'     => false,
                    "allows_multiple" => true,
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );
```

**Model**

```
protected $casts = [
    'schedule' => 'array',
];
```

**stored data in DB(schedule column):**

```
[{"day": "1", "range[]": ["1:30:00", "2:00:00"]}]
```

[image]

But selected data not showing on the page when it is multi selected.

**UPD:**
After Pedro's recomandation it's not help me. In DB it's storing as:

```
[{"day": "1", "range[]": ["0", "1"]}]
```

Comment: If selected only 1 parameter it's working fine but if more than 1 then it's not working

Answer (score 0):

viper.

when using multiple with default please use numeric keys like:

```php
'options' => [0 => 'option 0', 1 => 'option 1'],
'default' => [0,1]
```

I think Backpack can do something here to improve multiple string keys like

```php
'options' => ['option_0', 'option_1'],
'default' => ['option_0', 'option_1']
```

I will open an issue to discuss this in the package repository.

Thanks
Pedro

Comment: Pedro it's not helped me.